# What is an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is only continuous on the irrational numbers and zero?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Can someone give me an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is only continuous on the irrational numbers and zero ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discontinuity of Thomae Function on $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766543/discontinuity-of-thomae-function-on-mathbbq)

Comment: @user10354138 that function is zero on the irrationals, nonzero on the rationals, right? which is not what OP wants. But what OP wants, I think you can't get.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hmm... there are too many "and" there without some commas.  I was reading it as continuous on $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\cup\{0\}$ and discontinuous elsewhere, so you just need to modify Thomae at $0$.  But yes, reading it that way is probably what the OP wants.

Comment: @user10354138 true, the question could be expressed more clearly. Perhaps OP will clarify for us.

Comment: The question was clear, but I edited it. Apart from $0$, $f$ is discontinuous on the rationals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented above, an example of a function which is continuous at irrationals and discontinuous on rationals is the Thomae function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1n & \text{if }x=\frac{m}{n}, m,n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>0, \gcd(m,n)=1\\
0 & x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
Now just modify the value $f(0)$ so $f$ is also continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ as preimage of a closed set is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

What can be said about a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ that contains $\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be irrational. Consider a sequence of rationals converging to $\alpha$. If $f$ is zero on the rationals, and continuous on the irrationals, then it must be zero on the irrationals, so it's zero everywhere, so it's not discontinuous on the rationals.

Comment: And what happens when $f$ is not constant on the rationals?

Comment: Ah, you've edited the question to clarify. Good. Well, then, the function that @user10354138 has given should do the trick.